# LeakCanary build fails with build type that is not debug or release

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, leakcanary

My Android app has a third build type "qa".  I followed these instructions from LeakCanary's site: "if you have other build types than debug and release, you need to add a specific dependency for those too (xxxCompile)":

```
qaImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.6.2'
```

This results in a gradle sync error:

```
Could not find method qaImplementation() for arguments [com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.6.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

The same happens if I do `qaCompile`.  Here are my build types:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix " Dev"
        }
        qa {
            zipAlignEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
            versionNameSuffix " Test"
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }

        flavorDimensions "app" // Required by Gradle 3

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }
```

The instructions seem totally straightforward so I don't see what I might be missing.  Anyone have experience getting this setup to work?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, I just removed LeakCanary from my project.

Answer (score 4):

Correct, as the author said - add implementation with prefix of buildType.

For example, I have custom buildType called `releaseFreemium`. It takes all settings from build type - release - without additional options.

More info here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants .

[image]
[image]

Answer in FAQ of LeakCanary (https://github.com/square/leakcanary/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-fix-build-errors).

Comment: First, it's generally better to paste formatted code rather than a screenshot.  Second, do you see any reason why it would result in an error for me?  As far as I can tell I'm doing the same thing you are just with a different name.

Comment: @nasch `initWith release` is IMHO the key. As default there are release and debug build types. I understand creating custom build type as an element inherited by release or debug - never as stand alone build type.

Comment: Your provided gradle code is not quite correct. Please compare code with mine. I don't put `flavorDimensions` into buildType braces :-)

Comment: I had a chance to get back to this, and `initWith` didn't change anything, I'm still getting the same error.  Moving `flavorDimensions` outside the 'buildType' block also had no effect.

Comment: Okay, so please provide sample project on github so we could look at this closer.

Comment: Sorry it's closed source, I can't make it public.  I'll try to put together a minimal example though.

Comment: a minimal example to which I copied everything in my gradle files builds with no problem, so I'm kind of at a loss.  I don't think the manifest would be involved but I'll copy that over if I can't think of anything else.  The build tools and gradle wrapper are the same versions too.